# Dynamic WHERE clauses in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to execute this query

```
select * from locations where region=1 or region=2
```

but in certain cases I don't want to include the second clause in the WHERE (`or region=2`)
Is there a way to conditionally run the or statement?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that for maintainable code, you should name the columns explicitly rather than use `select *`. If the code in the question is just for illustration, this comment might not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the condition in the where statement

```
select * from locations 
where region=1 
or (region=2 and @checkRegion2=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want genralizable query, you can declare table variable for this (I assuming you're using SQL server):

```
declare @regions table (id int primary key)
```

and then fill it depending on condition:

```
insert into @regions select 1
if @use2 = 1
    insert into @regions select 2
```

now you can run this query:

```
select *
from location as l
where exists (select * from @regions as r where r.id = l.region)
```

or

```
select *
from location as l
where l.region in (select r.id from @regions as r)
```

Comment: Or use a join: `select * from location as l inner join @regions as r on r.region = l.region` (should work, untested, typed in browser, no SQL Server handy to test on, ... you know the drill)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yep, but I prefer `in` or `exists`, because it's clearly indicates I don't need any fields from @regions table, just want to filter out rows from location

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RUNAFTERBIT VARCHAR(10)
SET @RUNAFTERBIT = 'TRUE'

IF @RUNAFTERBIT = 'TRUE'
  SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS WHERE REGION = 1 OR REGION = 2
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS WHERE REGION = 1 
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM locations WHERE region=1 '

IF(@RUNAFTERBIT = 'TRUE')
BEGIN
    SET @Query = @Query + ' OR REGION = 2'
END

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: But please don't. **Try to think of some way to do it that doesn't involve dynamic SQL.** You lose out on parameter protection, code readability, query compilation and execution plan caching, and probably a whole bunch of other things. At best, it'll work the same. At worst, you'll sacrifice a great deal of performance for no gain.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Usually, dynamic SQL is my last way to do this types of things, however from my experience sometimes it could even perform better (if the where case is huge and complicated and depends on many parameters). Not in this case, for sure

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression can be used to perform short circuit evaluation under some circumstances:

```
declare @AlternateRegion as Int = 2;

select *
  from Locations
  where case
    when Region = 1 then 1
    when @AlternateRegion is not NULL then
      case when Region = @AlternateRegion then 1 else 0 end
    else 0
    end = 1
```

`CASE` does not reliably provide short circuit evaluation in the presence of aggregation functions.  See [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order)
 and [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case)
.